# How do I use a domain name on a dedicated hosting server?

Tags: domains, godaddy, webserver

I recently purchased a domain name from godaddy and am probably going to set up a dedicated server soon. Are there any articles that people know of which can help me set up my domain name on the dedicated server (peer1, rackspace, etc)?

A sub-question would be: how do I like the godaddy domain name to my IP address that I get on my dedicated server from one of these hosting companies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup of your domain on your dedicated server depends on a few things:

- What control panel comes with your server
- What webserver you'll be using (Apache, Nginx, etc)

If you're going to use IIS, then this [guide](http://www.simpledns.com/kb.aspx?kbid=1149) will walk you through the process of setting up more than one domain on your server.  If you ever plan on adding a second domain, I suggest this route.

To link your domain name to your IP address, you'll need to edit your DNS settings.  Again, there are some choices for you to make such as who you will use for your nameserver.  Once you know who your nameserver is, you'll need to point your GoDaddy domain to that nameserver.  On that nameserver, you'll need to create an A record that links your domain name to the IP of your server.

Comment: Running on a windows server with MS SQL and MailExchange